# How to listen to node http-proxy traffic?

Tags: http, node.js, proxy

I am using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). However, in addition to relaying HTTP requests, I also need to listen to the incoming and outgoing data.

Intercepting the response data is where I'm struggling. Node's `ServerResponse` object (and more generically the `WritableStream` interface) doesn't broadcast a `'data'` event. `http-proxy` seems to create it's own internal request, which produces a ClientResponse object (which does broadcast the `'data'` event) however this object is not exposed publically outside the proxy.

Any ideas how to solve this without monkey-patching node-http-proxy or creating a wrapper around the response object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Related issue in issues of node-http-proxy on Github seems to imply this is not possible. For future attempts by others, here is how I *hacked* the issue:

- you'll quickly find out that the proxy is only calling `writeHead()`, `write()` and `end()` methods of the `res` object
- since `res` is already an `EventEmitter`, you can start emitting new custom events
- listen for these new events to assemble the response data and then use it

```js
var eventifyResponse = function(res) {
  var methods = ['writeHead', 'write', 'end'];
  methods.forEach(function(method){
    var oldMethod = res[method]; // remember original method
    res[method] = function() {   // replace with a wrapper
      oldMethod.apply(this, arguments); // call original method
      arguments = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
      arguments.unshift("method_" + method);
      this.emit.apply(this, arguments); // broadcast the event
    };
  });
};

res = eventifyResponse(res), outputData = '';

res.on('method_writeHead', function(statusCode, headers) { saveHeaders(); });
res.on('method_write',     function(data) { outputData += data; });
res.on('method_end',       function(data) { use_data(outputData + data); });
proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, options)
```

Comment: this is great, thanks! However, I need to actually rewrite a header before it gets sent back to the client. Your example is only listening/recording the data, but doesn't change it. Any idea on how to actually change it before it gets sent back to the client?

Comment: @Tauren - if you need to send modified data, you really need 3 things: 1. read the incoming data, 2. modify it, 3. send it onwards. The whole point of the `node-http-proxy` is to encapsulate the proxying process - and in your case it wouldn't really help you much. So I suggest patching your proxy together using node's built-in HTTP server and mikeal's excellent [request library](https://github.com/mikeal/request) as HTTP client.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. That's the same conclusion that I had came to, but was hoping there might be some way to accomplish it and still use node-http-proxy. It is solving 99% of my needs, but there is this one issue that is causing me troubles.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple proxy server sniffing the traffic and writing it to console:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

//
// Create a proxy server with custom application logic
//
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

// assign events
proxy.on('proxyRes', function (proxyRes, req, res) {

    // collect response data
    var proxyResData='';
    proxyRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
        proxyResData +=chunk;
    });
    proxyRes.on('end',function () {


        var snifferData =
        {
            request:{
                data:req.body,
                headers:req.headers,
                url:req.url,
                method:req.method},
            response:{
                data:proxyResData,
                headers:proxyRes.headers,
                statusCode:proxyRes.statusCode}
        };
        console.log(snifferData);
    });

    //    console.log('RAW Response from the target', JSON.stringify(proxyRes.headers, true, 2));
});


proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    // collect request data
    req.body='';
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        req.body +=chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
    });

});

proxy.on('error',
    function(err)
    {
        console.error(err);
    });

// run the proxy server
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    // every time a request comes proxy it:
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'http://localhost:4444'
    });

});

console.log("listening on port 5556")
server.listen(5556);
```

Comment: How can I get this code working? I configured the browser to use port 5556 but nothing appears in the console when navigating to different websites...

Answer (score 0):

I tried your hack but it didn't work for me. My use case is simple: I want to log the in- and outgoing traffic from an Android app to our staging server which is secured by basic auth.

https://github.com/greim/hoxy/

was the solution for me. My node-http-proxy always returned 500 (while the direct request to stage did not). Maybe the authorization headers would not be forwarded correctly or whatever.

Hoxy worked fine right from the start.

```
npm install hoxy [-g]
hoxy --port=<local-port> --stage=<your stage host>:<port>
```

As rules for logging I specified:

```
request: $aurl.log()
request: @log-headers()
request: $method.log()
request: $request-body.log()


response: $url.log()
response: $status-code.log()
response: $response-body.log()
```

Beware, this prints any binary content.